# Typo3 showClickmenu not working for certain plugin-provided item types

Tags: javascript, plugins, typo3

I have a really old Typo3 plugin and some time ago (probably the problem is caused by a Typo3 upgrade; I currently use 4.7.11), users started to complain that the context menu of certain items in the backend does not work any more. The effect is limited on some tables, not all, but it looks like a class of items is either working or not.

The plugin does nothing special about the context menu, I would just expect the standard thing with the edit button etc. I understand from a web search that there changes have been made to the backend wrt. context menu. However, from the bug reports, it is not clear to me what I have to change, specifically because some of my stuff is working without modifications.

Is there any documentation about what I need to adapt in a plugin to work with the new context menu architecture?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

PS: The strange thing is that the context menu is not working in the standard file browser neither. This might be related, but I do not have a solution for that yet...

**Edit:** The webdev console of Firefox reports the error "xml or text declaration not at start of entity" for the menus that fail. The XML looks OK for me though:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t3ajax><data><clickmenu><htmltable><![CDATA[<div class="typo3-CSM-wrapperCM">

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="typo3-CSM">

                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="if(top.content.list_frame){top.content.list_frame.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'alt_doc.php?returnUrl='+top.rawurlencode(top.content.list_frame.document.location.pathname+top.content.list_frame.document.location.search)+'&amp;edit[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][240]=edit';}Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="if(top.content.list_frame){top.content.list_frame.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'alt_doc.php?returnUrl='+top.rawurlencode(top.content.list_frame.document.location.pathname+top.content.list_frame.document.location.search)+'&amp;edit[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][240]=edit';}Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-document t3-icon-document-open">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Bearbeiten</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="if(top.content.list_frame){top.content.list_frame.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'alt_doc.php?returnUrl='+top.rawurlencode(top.content.list_frame.document.location.pathname+top.content.list_frame.document.location.search)+'&amp;edit[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][-240]=new';}Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="if(top.content.list_frame){top.content.list_frame.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'alt_doc.php?returnUrl='+top.rawurlencode(top.content.list_frame.document.location.pathname+top.content.list_frame.document.location.search)+'&amp;edit[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][-240]=new';}Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-document t3-icon-document-new">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Neu</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="top.launchView('tx_visteaching_seminartopic', '240'); Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="top.launchView('tx_visteaching_seminartopic', '240'); Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-document t3-icon-document-info">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Info</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bgColor2">
                    <td colspan="2"><img src="clear.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="showClickmenu_raw('/typo3/alt_clickmenu.php?table=tx_visteaching_seminartopic&amp;uid=240&amp;listFr=1&amp;enDisItems=&amp;backPath=%7Ce633b347b6&amp;addParams=&amp;ajax=1&amp;reloadListFrame=1&amp;CB[el][tx_visteaching_seminartopic%7C240]=1&amp;CB[setCopyMode]=1');Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="showClickmenu_raw('/typo3/alt_clickmenu.php?table=tx_visteaching_seminartopic&amp;uid=240&amp;listFr=1&amp;enDisItems=&amp;backPath=%7Ce633b347b6&amp;addParams=&amp;ajax=1&amp;reloadListFrame=1&amp;CB[el][tx_visteaching_seminartopic%7C240]=1&amp;CB[setCopyMode]=1');Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-edit t3-icon-edit-copy">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Kopieren</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="showClickmenu_raw('/typo3/alt_clickmenu.php?table=tx_visteaching_seminartopic&amp;uid=240&amp;listFr=1&amp;enDisItems=&amp;backPath=%7Ce633b347b6&amp;addParams=&amp;ajax=1&amp;reloadListFrame=1&amp;CB[el][tx_visteaching_seminartopic%7C240]=1');Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="showClickmenu_raw('/typo3/alt_clickmenu.php?table=tx_visteaching_seminartopic&amp;uid=240&amp;listFr=1&amp;enDisItems=&amp;backPath=%7Ce633b347b6&amp;addParams=&amp;ajax=1&amp;reloadListFrame=1&amp;CB[el][tx_visteaching_seminartopic%7C240]=1');Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-edit t3-icon-edit-cut">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Ausschneiden</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bgColor2">
                    <td colspan="2"><img src="clear.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="showClickmenu_raw('/typo3/alt_clickmenu.php?table=tx_visteaching_seminartopic&amp;uid=240&amp;listFr=1&amp;enDisItems=&amp;backPath=%7Ce633b347b6&amp;addParams=&amp;ajax=1&amp;cmLevel=1&amp;subname=moreoptions');" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="showClickmenu_raw('/typo3/alt_clickmenu.php?table=tx_visteaching_seminartopic&amp;uid=240&amp;listFr=1&amp;enDisItems=&amp;backPath=%7Ce633b347b6&amp;addParams=&amp;ajax=1&amp;cmLevel=1&amp;subname=moreoptions');;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> </td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Weitere Einstellungen...</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="if(top.content.list_frame){top.content.list_frame.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'tce_db.php?redirect='+top.rawurlencode(top.content.list_frame.document.location.pathname+top.content.list_frame.document.location.search)+'&amp;data[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][240][hidden]=1&amp;prErr=1&amp;vC=31e89da0b5&amp;formToken=67e2328a3706432e0dd02d2f1e0923002537a3d0';}top.nav.refresh.defer(500, top.nav);Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="if(top.content.list_frame){top.content.list_frame.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'tce_db.php?redirect='+top.rawurlencode(top.content.list_frame.document.location.pathname+top.content.list_frame.document.location.search)+'&amp;data[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][240][hidden]=1&amp;prErr=1&amp;vC=31e89da0b5&amp;formToken=67e2328a3706432e0dd02d2f1e0923002537a3d0';}top.nav.refresh.defer(500, top.nav);Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-edit t3-icon-edit-hide">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Verbergen</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="var docRef=(top.content.list_frame)?top.content.list_frame:top.content.list_frame; docRef.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'alt_doc.php?edit[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][240]=edit&amp;columnsOnly=hidden'+'&amp;returnUrl='+top.rawurlencode(docRef.document.location.pathname+docRef.document.location.search);Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="var docRef=(top.content.list_frame)?top.content.list_frame:top.content.list_frame; docRef.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'alt_doc.php?edit[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][240]=edit&amp;columnsOnly=hidden'+'&amp;returnUrl='+top.rawurlencode(docRef.document.location.pathname+docRef.document.location.search);Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-document t3-icon-document-edit-access">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Sichtbarkeitseinstellungen</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bgColor2">
                    <td colspan="2"><img src="clear.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="if(top.content.list_frame &amp;&amp; confirm(String.fromCharCode(83,105,110,100,32,83,105,101,32,115,105,99,104,101,114,44,32,100,97,115,115,32,83,105,101,32,34,69,118,97,108,117,97,116,105,111,110,32,118,111,110,32,75,110,111,116,101,110,45,75,97,110,116,101,110,32,68,105,97,103,114,97,109,109,101,110,34,32,116,97,116,115,228,99,104,108,105,99,104,32,108,246,115,99,104,101,110,32,119,111,108,108,101,110,63,32,40,84,104,101,114,101,32,97,114,101,32,49,32,114,101,102,101,114,101,110,99,101,40,115,41,32,116,111,32,116,104,105,115,32,114,101,99,111,114,100,33,41)) ){top.content.list_frame.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'tce_db.php?redirect='+top.rawurlencode(top.content.list_frame.document.location.pathname+top.content.list_frame.document.location.search)+'&amp;cmd[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][240][delete]=1&amp;prErr=1&amp;vC=31e89da0b5&amp;formToken=67e2328a3706432e0dd02d2f1e0923002537a3d0';}top.nav.refresh.defer(500, top.nav);Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="if(top.content.list_frame &amp;&amp; confirm(String.fromCharCode(83,105,110,100,32,83,105,101,32,115,105,99,104,101,114,44,32,100,97,115,115,32,83,105,101,32,34,69,118,97,108,117,97,116,105,111,110,32,118,111,110,32,75,110,111,116,101,110,45,75,97,110,116,101,110,32,68,105,97,103,114,97,109,109,101,110,34,32,116,97,116,115,228,99,104,108,105,99,104,32,108,246,115,99,104,101,110,32,119,111,108,108,101,110,63,32,40,84,104,101,114,101,32,97,114,101,32,49,32,114,101,102,101,114,101,110,99,101,40,115,41,32,116,111,32,116,104,105,115,32,114,101,99,111,114,100,33,41)) ){top.content.list_frame.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'tce_db.php?redirect='+top.rawurlencode(top.content.list_frame.document.location.pathname+top.content.list_frame.document.location.search)+'&amp;cmd[tx_visteaching_seminartopic][240][delete]=1&amp;prErr=1&amp;vC=31e89da0b5&amp;formToken=67e2328a3706432e0dd02d2f1e0923002537a3d0';}top.nav.refresh.defer(500, top.nav);Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-edit t3-icon-edit-delete">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">L&#xf6;schen</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="typo3-CSM-itemRow" onclick="var docRef=(top.content.list_frame)?top.content.list_frame:top.content.list_frame; docRef.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'show_rechis.php?element=tx_visteaching_seminartopic%3A240'+'&amp;returnUrl='+top.rawurlencode(docRef.document.location.pathname+docRef.document.location.search);Clickmenu.hideAll();" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#dedede';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='';" oncontextmenu="var docRef=(top.content.list_frame)?top.content.list_frame:top.content.list_frame; docRef.location.href=top.TS.PATH_typo3+'show_rechis.php?element=tx_visteaching_seminartopic%3A240'+'&amp;returnUrl='+top.rawurlencode(docRef.document.location.pathname+docRef.document.location.search);Clickmenu.hideAll();;return false;">
                    <td align="center"> <span class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-document t3-icon-document-history-open">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="typo3-CSM-item">Verlauf/R&#xfc;ckg&#xe4;ngig</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>]]></htmltable><cmlevel>0</cmlevel></clickmenu></data></t3ajax>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context menu is rendered via a `AJAX` request. Make sure to have a look at the raw result with your browsers `network inspection tools` (Chrome and Firefox work best here). The raw result might contain an error message.

Also make sure to check the `PHP error log`.

I am not aware of any significant change to the context menu.

Comment: I have stepped through the JavaScript and found the AJAX request - but to be honest that stuff is that complex that I did not yet understand what is Happening here. The PHP log does not show any error...

Comment: There is an onclick handler. Nothing complex there. It just fetches the context menu from the server by passing the table and uid.

Comment: OK, I used the Firefox dev console and got a "xml or text declaration not at start of entity" for the AJAX response. The XML data is, however, syntactically correct. The only thing that looks suspicious to me is that there is an empty line at the begin of the response. In case of the file list, however, there does not seem a response at all, but only for files...

Comment: I found out that the requests that do not produce a result just take very long and end with an HTTP 500 - I will further investigate this.

Comment: Empty line usually means, that you have some whitespace after a PHP closing tag. But this should be no problem. Your error most come from something else.
In case of an 500, you should see this in the error log. If you enable debug output, then you should see the error in the dev console instead of the HTML response.

Comment: Wrt. HTTP 500, I found out that the PHP memory limit is too low, so this is no problem...

Comment: I found out that an Extension had empty lines in its PHP, which was emitted and caused the context menu to be invalid. See http://forge.typo3.org/issues/15951.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the javascript for the clickmenu in the file class.t3lib_treeview.php. It uses javascript not ajax.

```
    function wrapClickMenuOnIcon($str,$table,$uid='',$listFr=1,$add$
    {
         $backPath = rawurlencode($this->backPath).'|'.t3lib_div$
         $onClick = 'if(event.stopPropagation){event.stopPropaga$
         '","'.$uid.'","'.$listFr.'","'.
          str_replace('+','%2B',$enDisItems).'","'.
          str_replace('&','&amp;',addcslashes($backPath,'"')).'",$
          str_replace('&','&amp;',addcslashes($addParams,'"')).'"$
          return $returnOnClick ? $onClick : '<a href="javascript$
                                                    htmlspecialchar$
     }
```

Comment: The problem does not occur in the tree view, but in the list view. Does the list view use the same code?

Comment: The page tree uses different code, all other context menus share the code (AFAIK).

Comment: OK, then this is not the right place for me, because I do not have a problem with the page tree, but only with other views.